# Change Language in PHP

Tags: php, html

PHP

```
$this->data['months'] = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $this->data['months'][] = array(
            'text'  => strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)), 
            'value' => sprintf('%02d', $i)
        );

$_['months'][]        = array("Ocak","Şubat","Mart","Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran","Temmuz","Ağustos","Eylül","Ekim","Kasım","Aralık");
```

HTML

```
<select name="cc_expire_date_month">
                    <option value="01">January</option>
                    <option value="02">February</option>
                    <option value="03">March</option>
                    <option value="04">April</option>
                    <option value="05">May</option>
                    <option value="06">June</option>
                    <option value="07">July</option>
                    <option value="08">August</option>
                    <option value="09">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                  </select>
```

i couldn't change the language of the months. what should i change $_['months'][] to what ?again it wants too much detail please help i couldn't change language of that form select element

Comment: Why do you think your code should change the language? How does `$_['month']` relate to your HTML? Is that supposed to resemble gettext?

Comment: from php.net regarding `strftime()`, 'Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current locale set with setlocale().'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$weird_months=array("Ocak","Şubat","Mart","Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran","Temmuz","Ağustos","Eylül","Ekim","Kasım","Aralık");

$this->data['months'] = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $this->data['months'][] = array(
            'text'  => $weird_months[$i-1], 
            'value' => sprintf('%02d', $i)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your html into php and then create an session variable language:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["language"])){
    if($_SESSION["language"]=="EN"){
    include_once("languages/languageEN.php");
    }
    if($_SESSION["language"]=="WHATEVER"){
    include_once("languages/languageWHATEVER.php");
    }
}else{
    include_once("languages/languageEN.php");
}

              <select name="cc_expire_date_month">
                <option value="01"><?php echo MONTH1; ?></option>
                <option value="02"><?php echo MONTH2; ?></option>
                <option value="03"><?php echo MONTH3; ?></option>
                <option value="04"><?php echo MONTH4; ?></option>
                <option value="05"><?php echo MONTH5; ?></option>
                <option value="06"><?php echo MONTH6; ?></option>
                <option value="07"><?php echo MONTH7; ?></option>
                <option value="08"><?php echo MONTH8; ?></option>
                <option value="09"><?php echo MONTH9; ?></option>
                <option value="10"><?php echo MONTH10; ?></option>
                <option value="11"><?php echo MONTH11; ?></option>
                <option value="12"><?php echo MONTH12; ?></option>
              </select>
```

On languageEN.php or languageWHATEVER.php:

```
<?php
    define('MONTH_1','January');
    define('MONTH_2','February');
    define('MONTH_3','March');
    define('MONTH_4','April');
    define('MONTH_5','May');
    define('MONTH_6','June');
    define('MONTH_7','July');
    define('MONTH_8','August');
    define('MONTH_9','September');
    define('MONTH_10','October');
    define('MONTH_11','November');
    define('MONTH_12','December');
?>
```